# How to remove third-party menu bar elements

Tags: menu-bar, third-party

I would like to remove **third-party** **menu bar elements**, e.g. a menu left by an application which I have removed from the Applications folder.

I know that I can **rearrange** the elements if I **command-click** and **drag** them. And if they are made by Apple, control-dragging them away from the menu bar removes them. But with third-party elements the control-drag only allows for the rearrangement, but not for the **removal**.

I am looking for a method valid for *any* third-party elements, but to be specific, an example is Coppertino VOX music player, which has a menu item to manage the cloud library.
 - List item

Comment: If you include the names of the specific apps you might get more nibbles from folks who have experience with that app... IMHO

Comment: Tends to make me think the app would have had an uninstaller...

Comment: TIL you can rearrange menu bar elements by command+click and drag